# Is it possible to lock an application open? Launchd?

Tags: launchd

I have just installed an application called TeamViewer on my own and my very elderly mother's Macs. This is in order for me to help her online and occasionally use the remote control facility. However, because she is totally unfamiliar with the application and does not recognise it, she simply shuts it whenever she sees it, no matter how often I reopen it (when I am at home with her), nor how many times I ask her not to shut it. She simply forgets.

I have already added TeamViewer to the login items on my mother's user account, but that does not stop her from closing it.

I have read about launchd, or something similar, but realise that using such scripts or applications is beyond my own technical limits. Would it be possible for anyone to help me script the right instruction, or whatever it is called, to reopen the application every time my mother shuts it, or alternatively, to just keep the application locked open the whole time? I simply don't know what the options are.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about Screen Sharing instead? It's the method I use for my folk's Mac, 4000 miles away & can't be 'quit' by the user, as it's not ordinarily visible . I set it up initially by making an account of my own on the remote machine & enabling iCloud & remote management on it - that means I can always see it online, even if my account isn't logged in.

Comment: Can you hide the application so she can't close it? http://superuser.com/questions/217649/show-hide-application-icon-in-dock